# tcm:Error ErrorCode="80040302" can someone explain this error?

Tags: iis, tridion

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<tcm:Error ErrorCode="80040302" Category="16" Source="Kernel" Severity="2" xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0"><tcm:Line ErrorCode="80040302" Cause="false" MessageID="4613"><![CDATA[Unable to get list of Publication items.]]><tcm:Token>RESID_4485</tcm:Token><tcm:Token>RESID_4452</tcm:Token></tcm:Line><tcm:Line ErrorCode="80040302" Cause="false" MessageID="4394"><![CDATA[Unable to Initialize TDSE object.]]><tcm:Token>RESID_4537</tcm:Token><tcm:Token>TDSE</tcm:Token></tcm:Line><tcm:Line ErrorCode="80040302" Cause="true" MessageID="16226"><![CDATA[Access is denied for the user IIS APPPOOL\publishedlist.]]><tcm:Token>IIS APPPOOL\publishedlist</tcm:Token></tcm:Line><tcm:Details><tcm:CallStack><tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Security.AuthorizationManager.LoadAccessToken(String,IEnumerable`1,IEnumerable`1)</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Security.AuthorizationManager.LoadAccessToken(String,String)</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.Session..ctor(String,String,UserContext)</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.SystemFacade.InitializeUserContext(UserContext,String,String)</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>UtilitiesTDS.GetUserContext</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>TDSE.Initialize</tcm:Location><tcm:Location>TDSE.GetListPublications</tcm:Location></tcm:CallStack></tcm:Details></tcm:Error>
```

this error occurs while executing this line :

```
TridionCollection<Component> components = new TridionCollection<Component>(folder.GetListItems(ListColumnFilter.XMLListExtended, rowFilter), "[contains(@IsShared,'false') and contains(@IsLocalized,'false') ]");
```

Comment: Are you using the core service when you see this? Or are you accessing the CME (GUI)?

Comment: @Quirijn Error mentions `TDSE`, so most probably 2009 GUI or BusinessConnector

Comment: @Manoj Who is running your code? Does anything else work, any read or write action before this line?

Comment: @Quirijn How can we use tdse in sdl 2011?

Comment: @Manoj the TDSE still exists in 2011, and it works exactly like before - as far as I know

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the error itself is quite clear: User `IIS APPPOOL\publishedlist` has no permission to access Tridion. Now you need to understand why this user is trying to connect. There are several ways to resolve it. Try to figure out who is trying to connect with this user. Apparently IIS, but why (is it expected to connect with this user?)

- If you are logging in with user A and you see error like this, it means that you want to impersonate user A with `IIS APPPOOL\publishedlist`. Just add `IIS APPPOOL\publishedlist` to impersonation users of Tridion and it will be fine.
- If this user is some kind of service user that you are want to use to perform maintenance tasks or so - just create user in CM

Next time, please post some more details of what you were trying to do and where exactly you have a problem, otherwise your question will be downvoted and you will hardly get any answer.

Comment: Please look at the edit question may be it help you to understand the issue. thanks for your support